# How to invoke QMetaMethod with an array of QStrings?

Tags: c++, qt, reflection

QMetaObject system provides some basic reflection API. What I want to do is to call given slot or method that's available through this system.

However, the arguments and names of method are initially all QString values. The documentation shows an example:

> ```
> QString retVal;
> QByteArray normalizedSignature = QMetaObject::normalizedSignature("compute(QString, int, double)");
> int methodIndex = obj->metaObject()->indexOfMethod(normalizedSignature);
> QMetaMethod method = obj->metaObject()->method(methodIndex);
> method.invoke(obj,
>               Qt::DirectConnection,
>               Q_RETURN_ARG(QString, retVal),
>               Q_ARG(QString, "sqrt"),
>               Q_ARG(int, 42),
>               Q_ARG(double, 9.7));
> ```
>
> If the "compute" slot does not take **exactly one QString, one int and
>   one double** in the specified order, the call **will fail**.

Emphasis mine. Now with this example, I'm pretty clueless. It's clearly using templates, which are useless in dynamic context. I don't really see a purpose in using this API statically, when I could just as well call the method directly.

So let's say I have this function:

```
void invokeSlot(QObject* target, const QString& slotName, const QStringList& arguments) {
    // This is how I can get list of overloads by given name
    const QMetaObject* obj = target_->metaObject();
    QList<QMetaMethod> overloads;
    for (int i = 0, l = obj->methodCount(); i < l; ++i) {
        const QMetaMethod method = obj->method(i);
        if( method.name() == name )
            overloads.append(method);
    }        
    // Now how to convert the arguments?
}
```

You can assume that I have prepared this method for type conversion:

```
QVariant convertType(const QString& source, const QVariant::Type requiredType);
```

But how to pass the arguments even if I chose correct overload and convert strings to QVariants of required type?

Answer (score -1):

You can prepare this function:

```
QGenericArgument convertType(const QString& source, const QVariant::Type requiredType);
```

By using `switch`es and `Q_ARG` inside it.

Then a big `switch` on the argument count with `invoke`s in it.

Comment: Uh oh. Ok, I guess I don't have a choice.

Comment: This API won't work unless you use `QVariant`'s internals to get access to the data wrapped by `QVariant`, because a `QGenericArgument` doesn't hold the data, only points to it. This API wraps temporaries returned by `QVariant`, and by the time you've returned the `QGenericArgument`, the pointers-to-data it holds are already dangling :( If you've dynamically allocated the value, it will leak - since `QGenericArgument` does no memory management.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks for warning me. But is it possible to do what I want then? I know it works pretty fine from QtScript, and if all else fails, I'm actually planning to use QtScript to call the methods. But I'd prefer clean C++ solution.